# Я вижу двадцать двух студентов или двадцать два студента?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, числительные

**Я вижу двадцать двух студентов.

Я вижу двадцать два студента.**

Грамотно ли употреблять оба варианта?
Какой из них употребляется в книжном стиле?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить его галочкой.

Answer (score 3):

Вижу — кого? что? — В. п.
Студент — м. р., одушевленное сущ.

**Числительные два** (две), три, четыре в винительном падеже по-разному сочетаются с одушевленными и неодушевленными существительными:
**вижу** — кого? — **двух студентов** (учеников, учениц,  чудовищ) — В. п. = Р. п.;
вижу — что? — два стола (м. р.), две книги (ж. р.), два окна (ср. р.).

**В сочетаниях с составными числительными**, в которых последними элементами являются **два**, три, четыре, одушевленность существительных остается невыявленной:
**вижу** — кого? — **двадцать два студента**;
увидел — (что?) — двадцать два дома (неодуш.);
нанял — кого? — двадцать два работника (одуш.).

Конструкции типа ***вижу двадцать двух студентов***, нанял двадцать двух работников, прослушал двадцать трех пианисток **не соответствуют норме**.

[**О некоторых сочетаниях числительных с одушевленными существительными**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=STRqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA281&lpg=PA281&dq=%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%20(%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8)&source=bl&ots=aJAf6MR3Tw&sig=Fc7x3EOG1B6axbdFagGh0EewBhM&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_ttndx-zaAhXSUlAKHZnaAzsQ6AEwA3oECAAQSQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%20(%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8)&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу двадцать два студента. Это и книжный вариант.

Comment: Это и книжный вариант почему?